# How do I execute the python script within bash?

Tags: python, bash

I have security token generator python file and this file need to be consumed/executed by some bash file. The token.py file will returns a generated token and this token needs to be passed to a bash script file when connecting to Web Service.

One problem is that the python file has to be executed within a Virtual Environment where all the dependency packages are installed like the cryptography package.
On the shell command I need to run the following before I can successfully execute my token.py:
- scl enable python bash
- source /path/to/a/virtualenv/bin/activate
- then I can execute python /path/to/a/token.py

[Bash script code snippet attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U01hn.png)

Comment: instead of activating the virtual environment with `source` (which is a bashism thus not portable), you can launch the python executable in the `bin` folder of the venv

Comment: I have tried a couple of stuff on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/activating-virtualenv-and-running-python-script-in-bash-file but no success. Do you mean I should move my token.py inside the bin folder of my virtualenv then run it from there?